# Is there a freely usable database that details the voice actors starring in each show?

Tags: voice-acting

I'd like to determine a few statistics about voice acting:

1. who are the most prolific anime voice actors during each season;
2. which shows have employed the most voice talent;
3. how few/many voice actors it would take to cover most of the shows in a given season.

I've had a play with [VGMdb](https://vgmdb.net) but it didn't seem to be suited to answering any of these kinds of queries. Is there another more appropriate resource? It's fine whether the resource is in English or Japanese.

Answer (score 1):

[Usagi Doi](http://www.usagi.org/doi/seiyuu/databases.html) would be a good starting point. All though they no longer maintain a complete database, they have several database files publicly available which can be used for this purpose.

[Myanimelist People](https://myanimelist.net/people.php) could also be used. All though there is no api/database publicly available to my knowledge.

[Behind the voice actors](https://www.behindthevoiceactors.com/voice-actors/) this site covers more than only anime Seiyuu, and to my knowledge has no public api/database available.

For the later 2 sites scraping may be a possibility, all though you would have to take a look at their respective policies.

Comment: Usagi Doi looks great – it’s just a pity it only lists six shows for 2021, so it seems a bit underpopulated. Thanks for the other two – I’m hoping to avoid building a web scraper if I can (particularly due to licensing complications), but I can do it as a last resort. I’ll hold out a bit longer for an answer that provides an open database, but otherwise may accept this.